# How to handle the Linux socket revents POLLERR, POLLHUP and POLLNVAL?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, poll-syscall

I'm wondering what should be done when poll set these bits? Close socket, ignore it or what?

Comment: No context to this question, what is your intention?

Comment: Does it really need one? I'm just asking for best practices...

Comment: @user3790882 _'I'm just asking for best practices'_ You should be a bit more elaborate about this point though :P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: elaborate about what? The OP would like to know how to handle this. I really do not see how this is unclear. I am not sure what more context is needed...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `POLLHUP` means the socket is no longer connected. In TCP, this means FIN has been received and sent.

A `POLLERR` means the socket got an asynchronous error. In TCP, this typically means a RST has been received or sent. If the file descriptor is not a socket, `POLLERR` might mean the device does not support polling.

For both of the conditions above, the socket file descriptor is still open, and has not yet been closed (but `shutdown()` may have already been called). A `close()` on the file descriptor will release resources that are still being reserved on behalf of the socket. In theory, it should be possible to reuse the socket immediately (e.g., with another `connect()` call).

A `POLLNVAL` means the socket file descriptor is not open. It would be an error to `close()` it.

Answer (score 12):

It depend on the exact error nature. Use getsockopt() to see the problem:

```
int error = 0;
socklen_t errlen = sizeof(error);
getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void *)&error, &errlen);
```

Values: http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1793/

The easiest way is to assume that the socket is no longer usable in any case and close it.

Comment: For me I was getting POLLERR but... I had no way to detect what the error was! This answer seems like the best because it answers the more general question of "best practices" for handling POLLERR for network-programming.

Comment: I don't think this works in the general case. At least, Linux does not document that it can be used this way. `SO_ERROR` is documented to return the error status of the socket, but it's usage for detecting socket error state is only described for the `connect()` call, and not for any others.

Answer (score 6):

`POLLNVAL` means that the file descriptor value is invalid. It usually indicates an error in your program, but you can rely on `poll` returning `POLLNVAL` if you've closed a file descriptor and you haven't opened any file since then that might have reused the descriptor.

`POLLERR` is similar to error events from [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html). It indicates that a `read` or `write` call would return an error condition (e.g. I/O error). This does not include out-of-band data which `select` signals via its `errorfds` mask but `poll` signals via `POLLPRI`.

`POLLHUP` basically means that what's at the other end of the connection has closed its end of the connection. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html) describes it as

> The device has been disconnected. This event and POLLOUT are mutually-exclusive; a stream can never be writable if a hangup has occurred.

This is clear enough for a terminal: the terminal has gone away (same event that generates a SIGHUP: the modem session has been terminated, the terminal emulator window has been closed, etc.). `POLLHUP` is never sent for a regular file. For pipes and sockets, [it depends on the operating system](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/poll.html). Linux sets `POLLHUP` when the program on the writing end of a pipe closes the pipe, and sets `POLLIN|POLLHUP` when the other end of a socket closed the socket, but `POLLIN` only for a socket shutdown. Recent *BSD set `POLLIN|POLLUP` when the writing end of a pipe closes the pipe, and the behavior for sockets is more variable.

Answer (score 2):

**Minimal FIFO example**

Once you understand when those conditions happen, it should be easy to know what to do with them.

poll.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <fcntl.h> /* creat, O_CREAT */
#include <poll.h> /* poll */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, puts, snprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <unistd.h> /* read */

int main(void) {
    char buf[1024];
    int fd, n;
    short revents;
    struct pollfd pfd;

    fd = open("poll0.tmp", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    pfd.fd = fd;
    pfd.events = POLLIN;
    while (1) {
        puts("loop");
        poll(&pfd, 1, -1);
        revents = pfd.revents;
        if (revents & POLLIN) {
            n = read(pfd.fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
            printf("POLLIN n=%d buf=%.*s\n", n, n, buf);
        }
        if (revents & POLLHUP) {
            printf("POLLHUP\n");
            close(pfd.fd);
            pfd.fd *= -1;
        }
        if (revents & POLLNVAL) {
            printf("POLLNVAL\n");
        }
        if (revents & POLLERR) {
            printf("POLLERR\n");
        }
    }
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/6cc4af959b0ad0d90f2de6af51911315cf4497f7/posix/interactive/poll.c).

Compile with:

```
gcc -o poll.out -std=c99 poll.c
```

Usage:

```
sudo mknod -m 666 poll0.tmp p
./poll.out
```

On another shell:

```
printf a >poll0.tmp
```

**POLLHUP**

If you don't modify the source: `./poll.out` outputs:

```
loop
POLLIN n=1 buf=a
loop
POLLHUP
loop
```

So:

- `POLLIN` happens when input becomes available
- `POLLHUP` happens when the file is closed by the `printf`
- `close(pfd.fd);` and `pfd.fd *= -1;` clean things up, and we stop receiving `POLLHUP`
- `poll` hangs forever

This is the normal operation.

You could now repoen the FIFO to wait for the next `open`, or exit the loop if you are done.

**POLLNAL**

If you comment out `pfd.fd *= -1;`: `./poll.out` prints:

```
POLLIN n=1 buf=a
loop
POLLHUP
loop
POLLNVAL
loop
POLLNVAL
...
```

and loops forever.

So:

- `POLLIN` and `POLLHUP` and `close` happened as before
- since we didn't set `pfd.fd` to a negative number, `poll` keeps trying to use the `fd` that we closed
- this keeps returning `POLLNVAL` forever

So we see that this shouldn't have happened, and indicates a bug in your code.

**POLLERR**

I don't know how to generate a `POLLERR` with FIFOs. Let me know if there is way. But it should be possible with `file_operations` of a device driver.

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04.