# The poll() function returns a non-zero positive value with no events from the sockets i have registered for

Tags: c, sockets, networking, unix-socket

This continues to occur for an infinite amount of time until a valid event occurs on the corresponding socket. Then again, it goes back to normal behavior. Unable to trace the trigger for this issue.

What other events should I look for in the sockets other than the events I have registered for and why? I have currently registered for POLLIN & POLLHUP.

```
  while ( 1 )
    {
        //Calling POLL Function;
        //Sockets in List ( One Server Socket TCP )
        //Sockets of Open TCP Connections
        int rv = poll ( ufds , nfds , - 1 );

        if (rv == -1)
        {
            //Error Occured in POLL
        }
        else if ( rv == 0 )
        {
            //Time out fromData Recieved
        }
        else if ( rv > 0 )
        {
               //Look for events POLLIN or POLLHUP and act correspondingly
        }
  }
```

(MOST POSSIBLE)Trigger for the issue -

```
                    //Called by Main Thread when another thread is 
                    //polling on the respective socket_fd 
                    recv(socket_fd, buffer, 1024, MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

I am doing a MSG_PEEK to see whether the peer connected to this socket is alive.

Comment: Post the code concerned.

Comment: Please let me know if anything more is required.

Comment: AFAIK you need to initialize the `ufds` structure inside the loop, but don't quote me.

Comment: I have initialized them properly prior the poll() function call. Why does it require to be initialized inside the loop?

Comment: @EJP why would you need to do that? Can you explain where this idea comes from? Do you think that the `poll` call destroys the array  - because it doesn't.

Comment: Are you setting `POLLOUT` on any of the descriptors by any chance?

Comment: I haven't set `POLLOUT` @NikolaiNFetissov

Answer (score 1):

The `POLLHUP`, `POLLERR` and `POLLNVAL` events will cause [`poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/poll.html) to return even if these events have not been specified in `events` (in fact, setting these in `events` will be ignored). Check `revents` to see if any of these events happened for your file descriptors.

Comment: I will reply at the earliest after I try this tweak after I reproduce the issue.

   POLLNVAL
                     Invalid request: fd not open (only returned in revents;
                     ignored in events).
So do I close the socket and remove it from ufds array when this event occurs? @sander-de-dycker

Comment: @slim : have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791625/linux-socket-handling-revents-pollerr-pollhup-pollnval . For `POLLNVAL` specifically - that usually indicates a coding error : a socket that is not opened should not be in `ufds`.

Comment: POLLNVAL isn't the event for which poll comes out of the loop. I have made an edit which describes the trigger for the event

Comment: @slim : so, which was the event that woke up `poll` ?

Comment: As of now i don't know, I will check for all the returned events `POLLIN,POLLPRI,POLLOUT,POLLRDHUP,POLLERR,POLLHUP,POLLNVAL ` in every socket. If any other even i have to check for let me know.